# Find the poles and residue of the function $\frac{1}{z-\sin z }$ at $z=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$$\frac{1}{z-\sin z}$$
$$\frac{1}{z(1-\frac{\sin z}{z})}$$

the laurent's transform is also used to simplify the function.

the residue is found a $\frac{2*36*2}{5}$
but the actual answer is given as $\frac{3}{10}$
the residue is given as
The solution is incorrect and also the pole is of the order 3.

Answer (score 2):

One may write, by using a Taylor series expansion of $\sin z$, as $z \to 0$
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z-\sin z}&=\frac{1}{z-(z-\frac{z^3}{6}+\frac{z^5}{120}+O(z^7))}
\\\\&=\frac6{z^3}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{z^2}{20}+O(z^4)}
\\\\&=\frac6{z^3}\cdot \left(1+\frac{z^2}{20}+O(z^4)\right)
\\\\&=\frac6{z^3}+\frac{6}{20z}+O(z)
\\\\&=\frac6{z^3}+\frac{3}{10z}+O(z)
\end{align}
$$ giving the expected answer.

Comment: Wait, you flipped that denominator.  Quick explanation?

Comment: @SimpleArt As $u \to 0$, we have $\dfrac1{1-u}=1+u+O(u^2)$.

Comment: Ok.  And the $u\to0$ is not necessary.

Comment: Of course, but not false. It's just a point of view.

Comment: Thanks @OlivierOloa. I did the same but i did not know that the coefficient of the $z^{-1}$.

Comment: @Vinay5forPrime You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Taylor Series for the $\sin z$ function:

$$\sin z \approx z - \frac{z^3}{6} + \frac{z^5}{5!} + \ldots$$

In this way your denominator becomes

$$\frac{1}{\frac{z^3}{6} - \frac{z^5}{5!} + \ldots}$$

Collect a $z^3/6$ term:

$$\frac{1}{\frac{z^3}{6}\left(1 - \frac{z^2}{20}\right)} = \frac{6}{z^3} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{z^2}{20}}$$

Now the term $\frac{1}{1 - \frac{z^2}{20}}$  can be expanded with the Geometric Series, as long as $|z^2/20| < 1$:

$$\frac{6}{z^3} \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{z^{2k}}{20^k}$$

And the first terms of the series are

$$\frac{6}{z^3} + \frac{6}{20 z} + \frac{6 z^4}{400} + \ldots$$

And you now know that the residue is nothing but the coefficient of the $z^{-1}$ terms, which is

$$\frac{3}{10}$$

Also you can see the pole is order three, since you have a $z^{-3}$ factor in the series.

Comment: @AlanTurning I did not know that residues are the coefficient of $z^{-1}$. Nicely done dude.